# Ignore optional parameter in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Currently within my routes file I've got the following Route defined:

```
Route::get('{country}/{county}/{city?}/{id}', 'AdsController@show')->name('show')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

And within the `AdsController` I've got the following function:

```
public function show($country, $region, $city = null, $id) {
    if($city !== null)
        echo "we do something here extra";
    echo "Let's run our normal function";
}
```

The only issue is it appears that I must pass the `$city` variable? for instance, if I access `http://example.com/mycountry/myregion/mycity/1` it works fine? but if I was to run `http://example.com/mycountry/myregion/1` it shows a **404** is their anyway around this other than creating multiple routes?

Comment: optional things dont go before required things, as well in method signatures, it makes no sense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to create two separate routes. Laravel won't interpret a blank slash (/) as a null variable.

You could also pass a zero ('0') value in the route URI (example: /mycountry/myregion/0/1).

Also, you could place the optional route parameters at the end of the route. That may help.